# Ionic2 toggle change toggle button state based on method

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I've scoured all the stackoverflows I can find, but I can't seem to solve this problem. 
What I want is to toggle a  switch on page view to be whatever it was set to last. The value the toggle is supposed to be is the return value of a method that checks if it should be true or false.

```
<ion-toggle class="user-toggle" (ionChange)="userChange($event, user)" checked="isInChosen(user)"> </ion-toggle>
```

I confirmed that when I use the tag `checked="true"`, it works as expected and loads to be active on load. However, when `isInChosen(user)` is put, it always starts false regardless of the actual return value of the method. Rather, it doesn't call the method at all.
I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, and I probably am.

edit: source code for isInChosen(user)

```
isInChosen(user) {
   return this.chosenUsers.indexOf(user) != -1;
}
```

userChange(event, user)

```
userChange(event, user) {
    if (this.isInChosen(user)) {
        var index = this.chosenUsers.indexOf(user);
        this.chosenUsers.splice(index, 1);

    } else {
        this.chosenUsers.push(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also provide source code of functions *userChange* and *isInChosen*.

Answer (score 0):

I did miss something obvious there. Forgot that Angular2 changed things so I had to surround `checked` with square brackets, like so: `[checked]=`